# Parameters to generate globally unique id under linux

Tags: linux, uid

What parameters can I retrieve to generate a globally static unique id of system under non-root?

Can I use date of install in `/var/log/wtmp file(last | tail)` or it is unstable?

Can I use for it  result of `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/`?

I don't believe that MAC addresses are unique.

Comment: Unique by what measure? Globally, in your network, on the computer?

Comment: You would need a globally centralized entity to check the uniqueness of your IDs

Comment: For example, i can use pn+sn of hdd, but i don't know how to retrieve hdd pn.

Answer (score 0):

`uuidgen`

It's usually found in `/usr/bin/`

```
nyancat ~ # uuidgen
488bc393-a4f5-4a83-8df8-8c15e737dcc5
nyancat ~ #
```

Comment: [nyaapa@nyaapa-nb-nx ~]$ uuidgen 
fe2eee97-502a-4706-b2ad-ff1608ba7b35

[nyaapa@nyaapa-nb-nx ~]$ uuidgen 
8f270ae0-9e22-472d-93e3-d5883f24397c

unstable

Comment: Yes, the "unstability" is what guarantees the uniqueness. You will have to store it in a file somewhere.

Comment: What you seem to want is a unique hash for the system.  That's impossible unless you define which components are the "system".  If you see the system as the CPU, HDD, Motherboard, RAM, then you will by definition get a *different* system when you upgrade the RAM or change the HDD.

Comment: it's ok, i'd like to use HDD/Motherboard/CPU sn and pn, but i don't know how to get them.

Comment: I see!  I suggest you open a new question asking specifically about how to access HDD, motherboard and CPU serial numbers.  If you have them, then you can apply a cryptographic 128-bit hash over all the values to get a unique system id.